# Knockout filtered array issue

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, knockout.js, binding

I have a table containing "device" data, when the user selects a device, the device form is filled. The **device type** drop-down list contains all the device types and the device type of the chosen device is automatically selected. There is also a **device model** drop-down list that displays only the models related to the selected device type. When the user select a device from the device list, the form is well populated and all works, but I wish that the device models drop-down will also update **when the user manually selects another type of device from the device drop-down**, and this is not working.

[image]

Snippet:

```
<select data-bind="options: selectedDevice() ? modelsByDeviceType(selectedDevice().DeviceTypeID) : null, optionsText: 'DeviceModelName', optionsValue: 'DeviceModelID', value: selectedDevice() ? selectedDevice().DeviceModelID : 0, optionsCaption: ''"></select>

self.modelsByDeviceType = function (selectedDeviceType) {
      return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.deviceModels(), function (m) {
        return (m.DeviceTypeID === selectedDeviceType);
      });
    };
```

Full code: https://jsfiddle.net/rickhaar/9aLvd3uw/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your currently work with static data, you need to change it to knockout observables, then your values would update 2-way. Mapping plugin does the trick for you:

```js
function vm() {

  var self = this;

  var devicesData = [{
    DeviceID: 1,
    DeviceName: 'DVR1',
    DeviceTypeID: 1,
    DeviceModelID: 1
  }, {
    DeviceID: 2,
    DeviceName: 'DVR2',
    DeviceTypeID: 1,
    DeviceModelID: 2
  }, {
    DeviceID: 3,
    DeviceName: 'Cam1',
    DeviceTypeID: 2,
    DeviceModelID: 3
  }, {
    DeviceID: 4,
    DeviceName: 'Cam2',
    DeviceTypeID: 2,
    DeviceModelID: 4
  }];

  var deviceTypesData = [{
    DeviceTypeID: 1,
    DeviceTypeName: 'DVR'
  }, {
    DeviceTypeID: 2,
    DeviceTypeName: 'Camera'
  }];

  var deviceModelsData = [{
    DeviceModelID: 1,
    DeviceTypeID: 1,
    DeviceModelName: 'BOSH AN 5000'
  }, {
    DeviceModelID: 2,
    DeviceTypeID: 1,
    DeviceModelName: 'Aver NEH1116HN'
  }, {
    DeviceModelID: 3,
    DeviceTypeID: 2,
    DeviceModelName: 'Axis M1054'
  }, {
    DeviceModelID: 4,
    DeviceTypeID: 2,
    DeviceModelName: 'FLIR A65'
  }];

  self.devices = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.deviceTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.deviceModels = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.selectedDevice = ko.observable();

  self.init = function() {
    ko.mapping.fromJS(devicesData, {}, self.devices);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(deviceTypesData, {}, self.deviceTypes);
    ko.mapping.fromJS(deviceModelsData, {}, self.deviceModels);
  };

  self.selectDevice = function(index, item) {
    self.selectedDevice(item);
  };
  self.modelsByDeviceType = function(selectedDeviceType) {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.deviceModels(), function(m) {
      return (m.DeviceTypeID() === selectedDeviceType());
    });
  };

  self.init();

  return self;
}

ko.applyBindings(vm());
```

```css
.selectedRow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.js"></script>
<table id="tblData" class="dataTable" border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Device ID</th>
      <th>Device Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: devices">
    <tr data-bind="click: selectDevice.bind($data, $index()), css: { selectedRow: selectedDevice() === $data }">
      <td data-bind="text: DeviceID"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: DeviceName"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<table border="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Name</td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" style="width:80px" data-bind="value: selectedDevice() ? selectedDevice().DeviceName : ''" />
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Type</td>
      <td>
        <select data-bind="options: deviceTypes, optionsText: 'DeviceTypeName', optionsValue: 'DeviceTypeID', value: selectedDevice() ? selectedDevice().DeviceTypeID : 0, optionsCaption: ''"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Model</td>
      <td>
        <select data-bind="options: selectedDevice() ? modelsByDeviceType(selectedDevice().DeviceTypeID) : null, optionsText: 'DeviceModelName', optionsValue: 'DeviceModelID', value: selectedDevice() ? selectedDevice().DeviceModelID() : 0, optionsCaption: ''"></select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```